# System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled HResult=-2146233036 ... at CurrentDomain_UnhandledException

Tags: c#, static, isolatedstoragefile

Presently, I am attempting to write error logs to a disk file using isolated storage.  Suddenly, I started receiving the following exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'MyAppUtilities.ErrorLogger' threw an exception.
  Source=MyAppUtilities
  TypeName=MyAppUtilities.ErrorLogger
  StackTrace:
       at MyAppUtilities.ErrorLogger.AuditMethodError(Exception exc, String threadName,    String service)
       at MyWatchdog.Program.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) in c:\DataService\MyWatchdog\Program.cs:line 20
  InnerException: System.ArgumentNullException
      HResult=-2147467261
      Message=Value cannot be null.
  Parameter name: path
      Source=mscorlib
      ParamName=path
      StackTrace:
        at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
        at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
        at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
        at MyAppUtilities.ErrorLogger..cctor() in c:\DataService\DataServiceUtilities\ErrorLogger.cs:line 57
   InnerException:
```

Here is basically the code I am using to write error messages:

```
    private static Assembly _assembly =
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    private static string _errorLogFile =
        _assembly.FullName + ".log";
    private static IsolatedStorageFile _isoStore =
        IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(
        IsolatedStorageScope.User |
        IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly,
        null,
        null);
    private static IsolatedStorageFileStream _isoStream =
        new IsolatedStorageFileStream(_errorLogFile,
        FileMode.OpenOrCreate, _isoStore);

    public static void ApplicationAudit(string message)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_isoStream))
        {
            _isoStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            sw.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------" +
                "------------------------------");
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + message);
        }
    }
```

Please note that, before I started using isolated storage, it worked fine when just writing to a file in the same directory as the executable.  I have spent some time searching the internet, but haven't found any posts with the same exception together with the inner exception as the one I am receiving.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I am receiving the above error?  TIA.

Comment: This error usually happens when there is an error in a static constructor somewhere. You need to check the constructor for possible errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to assume that your static properties get initialized in a fixed sequence.

If you need a sequence, write a static constructor and initialize them in the sequence you need them initialized.

For example, who says that `_assembly` is already initialized in this line:

```
private static string _errorLogFile = _assembly.FullName + ".log";
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  When I tested in debug mode, it worked fine, but after I installed the application to run it in a "live" situation, it must have caused the initializers to execute in a different order, which caused the error.